# Play audio infinitely with discord.js

Tags: javascript

I'm making a discord bot that joins the channel while it's active and plays an audio clip on repeat.

I tried doing this by calling the function recursively:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
let vc = client.channels.get(voiceChannel);

vc.join().then(connection => {

    function play (connection) {
        const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fh0_sjZGJSc', { filter: 'audioonly' });
        const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions)
        dispatcher.on('end', play(connection));
    }

    play(connection)
})
});
```

but when I run it, I get this error:

```
Error: spawn ffmpeg EAGAIN
at _errnoException (util.js:999:13)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:201:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:389:16)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
```

Can anyone tell me how I can put an audio loop on repeat forever with discord.js? Thanks!

Comment: Does it play once then fail to repeat, or a number of times, or not play at all? Can you try playing a stream that you already have locally rather than downloading it from YouTube every time? You could well be hitting a YouTube throttling limit as well as a Discord one. And it's worth working out whether it's ytdl that's calling ffmpeg or discord.js if you don't already know: ideally you'd get the audio into a format that Discord supports without any more conversion before you start playing. And finally what are your streamOptions set to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as you join the voice channel you set the following listener:

```
dispatcher.on('end', play(connection));
```

Note that you are not giving a callback function here; instead you are calling play immediatly again. The error you are seeing is caused because you recursively spawned too many instances of FFMPEG (The library ytldl uses to transcode the video). To solve this you simply have to give an actual callback function like this:

```
dispatcher.on('end', () => { 
    play(connection);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I no longer use this bot and I'm too lazy to fire something up to test this again, but I recon I could have been able to acheive the same result with the following code:

`dispatcher.on('end', play.bind(null, connection)`