# Looping an audio file discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been making this code for my discord bot to play an audio file and it works great but I can't figure how to loop the track can anyone help?

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL ID")
    if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
    channel.join().then(connection => {
        connection.play(path.join(__dirname, 'FILE NAME'))
    }).catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play audio infinitely with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281723/play-audio-infinitely-with-discord-js)